# administrate gem deprecations on relations with class names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, administrate

A model `Transaction`

```
belongs_to :consumer, class_name: 'User'
```

The administrate gem automatically picks up this relation and includes both the model relation and the id

```
ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
  user: Field::BelongsTo,
  consumer: Field::BelongsTo.with_options(class_name: "User"),
  consumer_id: Field::Number,
```

In an attempt to make the transaction searchable by the relation

```
  consumer: Field::BelongsTo.with_options(
    class_name: "User",
    searchable: true,
    searchable_fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'mobile']
  ),
```

There is an error complaining about user being nil

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

def display_resource(user)
  user ? user.last_name + ', ' + user.first_name : "No user provided"
end
```

which in the stack is invoking the user_dashboard.  *This error occurs also when using the auto-generated* `consumer: Field::BelongsTo.with_options(class_name: "User")`  definition of ATTRIBUTE_TYPES

user.nil is a misleading error, as:

```
> Transaction.where('consumer_id IS NULL').size
=> 0
```

*the same occurs with user_id*
If the class_name is removed, the error response is intuitively expected: `uninitialized constant Consumer`.

The [documentation for customizing dashboards](http://administrate-demo.herokuapp.com/customizing_dashboards) indicates for option setting:

```
:class_name (deprecated) - Specifies the name of the associated class.
```

but the resulting removal shows it is necessary.  The consumer_id, if invoked in the collection of transactions, is shown properly.

How can this consumer be displayed?

administrate (0.14.0)
rails (6.0.3.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this code and this error:

```rb
# The code
def display_resource(user)
  user ? user.last_name + ', ' + user.first_name : "No user provided"
end

# The error
# !> undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

The error is not about the user being nil. The error says that you are trying to apply `+` to `nil`, and you are **not** trying to apply `+` to the user: you are trying to apply it to `user.last_name` and `user.first_name` (as well as `", "`).

What is nil is one of these values that you expect 1) to be present, and 2) to be strings. A possible way for this to fail is if a user is missing a first name.

Here's a way around that possibility:

```rb
def display_resource(user)
  user ? [user.last_name, user.first_name].compact.join(", ") : "No user provided"
end
```